# confirm dialog in php when deleting data

Tags: php

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ5UF.jpg)

I have my code here. But when I click the button, doesn't have effect at all.

```
echo "<td>
<form action='http://localhost:1130/gradsys/subjects/delete.php?lrn=" . $row->lrn . "' method='POST' onsubmit='return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit this data?')'>
<div class='btn btn-danger delete-btn'>
<span class='fa fa-trash fa-fw'>
</span>Delete
</div>
</form>
</td>";
```

thanks to those who will help

Comment: Works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/aux4yu11/  Are you sure this is even rendering to the HTML correctly?  You appear to have a quoting error in there.  (Mixing three languages in the same line of code can *very easily* lead to that.)

Comment: do you know how to fix?

Comment: Use double-quotes for your HTML attributes.  Put the HTML outside of PHP blocks instead of as `echo` statements.  Separate the JavaScript from the HTML by attaching event handlers instead of writing in-line JavaScript in the `onsubmit` attribute.

Comment: it is because this button is in table in my php. if im going to bring it out, it will not user friendly

Comment: None of my suggestions change the user experience in any way.  I'm only suggesting that you change how you organize your code so that you can avoid quoting errors.  Alternatively, you can just keep the quoting error.

Comment: im sorry im a noob in php

Answer (score 0):

This code has a quoting error here:

```
onsubmit='return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit this data?')'
```

A single-quote string inside of a single-quote string can't be parsed, so this results in invalid HTML/JavaScript.

Consider that you're mixing *three different languages* on *one line of code* (PHP, HTML, JavaScript).  This can *very easily* lead to quoting errors.

A couple of suggestions...

**Separate PHP from HTML**

Why use an `echo` statement for all of that HTML?  Just put it outside of PHP tags in the first place.  Something like this:

```
?>
<td>
    <form action="http://localhost:1130/gradsys/subjects/delete.php?lrn=<?php=$row->lrn; ?>" method="POST">
        <div class="btn btn-danger delete-btn">
            <span class="fa fa-trash fa-fw"></span>
            Delete
        </div>
    </form>
</td>
<?php
```

**Use double-quotes for HTML attributes**

Note in the code above that the single-quotes in the HTML have been replaced with double-quotes.  This is technically more correct for the HTML spec.

**Separate JavaScript from HTML**

Note also in the code above that I removed the `onsubmit` attribute entirely.  Instead of trying to write strings-within-strings (within strings), separate that code from the HTML markup.  Later, in JavaScript, you might have something like this:

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to submit this data?'))
        this.submit();
});
```

---

Ultimately there are a number of different ways to accomplish what you're trying to do with this code.  But the idea is that keeping different languages cleanly separated will make your code easier to support and help avoid typographical errors from mixing those languages.

Comment: is that will work if my table structure is this? (on my question, with link)

Comment: @Blances: Is this suggestion *not* working in some way?  Did you *try*?  All that picture shows is the user interface.  I'm not suggesting that you change your user interface at all.  So it's not clear what you're asking at this point.

Comment: but, doesn't have effect again. is there any function? because i just did what you said

Comment: where im gonna put this?

`document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to submit this data?'))
        this.submit();
});`

Comment: @Blances: That's JavaScript code, so you'd put it in a `<script>` element.

Comment: @Blances: Alternatively you *can* keep the JavaScript in-line with the HTML.  Just fix the quotes.  Maybe use double-quotes for the HTML attributes and single-quotes for the JavaScript string literal.  At least separating the PHP component from the HTML/JavaScript would make that easier.

Comment: last question

`document.querySelector('delete.php').addEventListener('submit', function(e){`

am i right? that the queryselection must the page delete?

Comment: @Blances: Why are you using `delete.php` as the query selector?  Where did you get that idea at all?  There are no HTML elements in your markup called `<delete class="php">` (I hope), so that selector simply won't find anything.  `form` as a selector, however, will find `<form>` elements.

Comment: @Blances: Given that you replaced `form` with `delete.php`, I have my doubts that you've implemented this correctly.  But I can't help with code you're not showing in the question.  "I wrote some code, but it's not working" isn't an answerable question.